# Uncaught TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.firestore is not a function in Vue js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error in my firebase.js  and I got Uncaught TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.firestore is not a function in my console I tried to import firebase in different ways, but neither way solve my problem.

```
 import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

// firebase init - add your own config here
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get `firestore` from `firebase`. However in your code, `firebase` is corresponding to `firebase/app`.

Your initialization for `const db` must come from `firebase/firestore`.

Try this:

```
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
const db = getFirestore();
```

Firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9_1

Moreover, you will probably get the same issue for `firebase.auth()`:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
```

Firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start